# Display Hierarchical Data From Table In Twig Template

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, twig, hierarchy

I am working with Symfony2 and Twig: I have a table that is set up to handle hierarchical data with Doctrine. It is a list of categories with parent->children->sub_children->sub_sub_children etc... Many many variations.

I am able to display them on the page like so, but the issue is there is no "indentation" to show which element belongs to what parent or child or child child etc etc.

```
 <table class="table" id="tableList">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Category Name</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for productCategory in productCategories %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ productCategory.name }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I'd like the list to look something like this:

```
 Parent 
      Child
           Child
 Parent
      Child
 Parent
      Child
           Child
                Child
```

Instead of like this:

```
 Parent
 Child
 Child
 Child
 Parent
 Child
 Parent
 etc.
 etc.
```

Original Entity:

```
 <?php

 namespace WIC\ProductCategoryBundle\Entity;

 use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
 use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
 use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
 use WIC\CommonBundle\DoctrineExtensions\Mapping\Annotation as Common;
 use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


 /**
  * ProductCategory
  *
  * @ORM\Table()
  * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Gedmo\Tree\Entity\Repository\NestedTreeRepository")
  * @Gedmo\Tree(type="nested")
  * @Common\Loggable(logEntryClass="WIC\ProductCategoryBundle\Entity\ProductCategoryLog")
  * @Common\Accountable
  * @Gedmo\SoftDeleteable(fieldName="deletedAt")
  */
 class ProductCategory
 {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 * @Common\Versioned
 * @Assert\NotBlank(message="Location Name Cannot Be Left Blank.")
 */
protected $name;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeLeft
 * @ORM\Column(name="lft", type="integer")
 */
protected $lft;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeLevel
 * @ORM\Column(name="lvl", type="integer")
 */
protected $lvl;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeRight
 * @ORM\Column(name="rgt", type="integer")
 */
protected $rgt;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeRoot
 * @ORM\Column(name="root", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
protected $root;

/**
 * @Gedmo\TreeParent
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="ProductCategory", inversedBy="children")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="parent_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="SET NULL")
 */
protected $parent;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="ProductCategory", mappedBy="parent")
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"lft" = "ASC"})
 */
protected $children;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product", mappedBy="productCategories", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $products;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="created_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Common\Blameable(on="create")
 */
private $createdBy;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\UserBundle\Entity\User")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="updated_by", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @Common\Blameable(on="update")
 */
private $updatedBy;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account", inversedBy="productCategorys", cascade={"remove","persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="account_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false, onDelete="CASCADE")
 * @Common\Versioned
 * @Common\Blameable(on="create")
 */
protected $account;


/**
 * @var datetime $created
 *
 * @Common\Timestampable(on="create")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
 */
private $created;

/**
 * @var datetime $updated
 *
 * @Common\Timestampable(on="update")
 * @ORM\Column(type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
protected $updated;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="deletedAt", type="datetime", nullable=true)
 */
private $deletedAt;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->products = new ArrayCollection();
}


/**
 * Get id
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return ProductCategory
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}


public function setLvl(ProductCategory $lvl = null)
{
    $this->lvl = $lvl;
}

public function getLvl()
{
    return $this->lvl;
}


public function setParent(ProductCategory $parent = null)
{
    $this->parent = $parent;
}

public function getParent()
{
    return $this->parent;
}

/**
 * Set account
 *
 * @param \WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account $account
 * @return User
 */
public function setAccount(\WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account $account = null)
{
    $this->account = $account;

    return $this;
}


/**
 * Get account
 *
 * @return \WIC\AccountBundle\Entity\Account
 */
public function getAccount()
{
    return $this->account;
}

/**
 * Add product
 *
 * @param \WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product
 * @return Product
 */
public function addProduct(\WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product)
{
    $this->products[] = $product;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove product
 *
 * @param \WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product
 */
public function removeProduct(\WIC\ProductBundle\Entity\Product $product)
{
    $this->products->removeElement($product);
}

/**
 * Set products
 *
 * @return Product
 */
public function setProducts($products)
{
    $this->products = $products;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get products
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection
 */
public function getProducts()
{
    return $this->products;
}

/**
 * Set updated
 *
 * @param \DateTime $updated
 * @return User
 */
public function setUpdated($updated)
{
    $this->updated = $updated;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get updated
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getUpdated()
{
    return $this->updated;
}

/**
 * Set deletedAt
 *
 * @param \DateTime $deletedAt
 * @return User
 */
public function setDeletedAt($deletedAt)
{
    $this->deletedAt = $deletedAt;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get deletedAt
 *
 * @return \DateTime
 */
public function getDeletedAt()
{
    return $this->deletedAt;
}

public function getOptionLabel()
{
    return str_repeat(
            html_entity_decode('&nbsp;', ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'),
            ($this->getLvl() + 0 ) * 3
    ) . $this->getName();
}


}
```

Anyone know how to accomplish this?

Thanks so much!

Comment: Can you post your entity structure for `productCategory`?  Need to know how your parent and children categories are related and accessed in order to help with the code to iterate through them.

Comment: Edited the original post to reflect, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The indentation will be much easier using an unordered list because they automatically get indented by the browser's default user-agent stylesheet.  This should do it:

Add this method to your ProductCategory entity:

```
public function getChildren() {
    return $this->children;
}
```

and this in your twig template

```
{% for productCategory in productCategories %}
    {{ _self.display_tree(productCategory) }}
{% endfor %}

{% macro display_tree(level) %}
    <ul>
        <li>{{ level.name }}
        {% if level.children|default() %}
            {% for child in level.children %}
                {{ _self.display_tree(child) }}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        </li>
    </ul>
{% endmacro %}
```

Comment: Thanks Ken for giving me an answer, but I am having a bit of an issue. I am getting this error once I installed the code:

Method "children" for object "WIC\ProductCategoryBundle\Entity\ProductCategory" does not exist in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/src/WIC/ProductCategoryBundle/Resources/views/ProductCategory/list.html.twig at line 58

Comment: Oh, I just looked at your entity and you need to add a `getChildren()` method.  Updating my answer.

Comment: Oh, you may also need to set `children` as an `ArrayCollection` in your `__construct()` in the `ProductCategory` entity the same way that you did the products.

Comment: I added this in the entity __construct(): $this->children = new ArrayCollection();

Comment: Now I get this error: Method "name" for object "Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection" does not exist in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/symfonydev/src/WIC/ProductCategoryBundle/Resources/views/ProductCategory/list.html.twig at line 57

Comment: Its something to do with this line: {{ level.name }}

Comment: can you replace that line with {{ dump(level) }} and post the results or do a pastebin?

Comment: Oops, think I figured out the issue, updating my answer with a for loop to iterate through the children in the twig template.

Comment: Twig block in answer updated with the nested for loop to handle the children.

Comment: No problem, that should handle an unlimited levels of categories.  Always glad to help!

Comment: Well, after looking at my list of items it looks like the script is sprinkling the elements randomly on the page, sometimes one element may appear 3 or 4 times in weird positions where it shouldn't, any thoughts why this may be happening. Thanks!

Comment: Looks like it is making children and sibling elements parents, but then it will also add the children and siblings elements randomly under the parent elements.

Comment: What's probably happening is that your query that fetches the `productCategories` and is then is passed into the view is probably loading ALL `productCategories` and not just the top-level ones.

So you probably need to add some logic into your query to only fetch `productCategories` that should be "top-level" or "root" categories.

Comment: Looking at your structure, you should probably just limit your query for `productCategories` to only include categories with a `lvl == 0` (assuming that's how you're using it) which should give you only your top-level

Comment: Thanks Ken, yeah thats what I figured it had to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little upgrade to previous answer.

```
<ul>
{% for productCategory in productCategories %}
    {{ _self.display_tree(productCategory) }}
{% endfor %}
</ul>

{% macro display_tree(level) %}
    <li>{{ level.name }}
    {% if level.children|default() %}
        <ul>
        {% for child in level.children %}
            {{ _self.display_tree(child) }}
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    {% endif %}
    </li>
{% endmacro %}
```

This would build better-looking html.