# Symfony Tree like structure in Twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have 3 entities

1. Group
2. Sub group
3. Product

And I get the data by joining these tables

`Group-SubGroup(OneToMany)` and `Product-SubGroup(ManyToMany)`

Data:

```
+---------------+------------+----------+
|     Group     |  Subgroup  | Product  |
+---------------+------------+----------+
| Food          | Fruits     | Apple    |
| Food          | Fruits     | Orange   |
| Food          | Vegetables | Brinjal  |
| Food          | Vegetables | Onion    |
| Food          | Vegetables | Potato   |
| Food          | Vegetables | Zucchini |
| Clothes       | Men        | Jeans    |
| Clothes       | Men        | Shirts   |
| Clothes       | Women      | Jeans    |
| Clothes       | Women      | Skirt    |
+---------------+------------+----------+
```

What I want to acheive is Tree like structure using twig

```
Group     
  Subgroup   
        Product  
Group     
  Subgroup  
        Product  
        Product  
Group     
  Subgroup  
       Product  
       Product  
       Product
```

Any Idea how can I achieve this in twig i looked up [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19433837/display-hierarchical-data-from-table-in-twig-template) but didnt understand..??

Answer (score 0):

Well I guess you could run it this way (if I get it right)

```
{% for group in groups %}
    {% for subgroup in group.subgroups %}
        {% for product in subgroup.products %}
            // display your products
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```